# SQL Pivot to create 2 columns per row

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this:

| Date | Name | Actual | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-14 | Bob | 15 | 15 |
| 2023-03-14 | Jim | 9 | 5 |
| 2023-03-14 | Steve | 10 | 9 |
| 2023-03-15 | Bob | 11 | 11 |
| 2023-03-15 | Jim | 16 | 16 |
| 2023-03-15 | Steve | 5 | 12 |

The Name column isn't always the same depending on who is working so the pivot has to be dynamic.
I want the table to look like this:

| Date | Bob_Actual | Bob_Target | Jim_Actual | Jim_Target | Steve_Actual | Steve_Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-14 | 15 | 15 | 9 | 5 | 10 | 9 |
| 2023-03-15 | 11 | 11 | 16 | 16 | 5 | 12 |

I was able to get this desired result if I just dynamically pivot on target, but I can't figure out how to pivot both the target and the actual

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from yt
                    group by Name
                    order by Name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Date,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Date, Name, Target
                from yt
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Target)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

I used the above code to get it to work for just target, but am not sure how to add actual

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use pivots, they're not flexible enough, try conditional aggregation instead:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO #yt
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'2023-03-14', N'Bob', 15, 15)
    ,   (N'2023-03-14', N'Jim', 9, 5)
    ,   (N'2023-03-14', N'Steve', 10, 9)
    ,   (N'2023-03-15', N'Bob', 11, 11)
    ,   (N'2023-03-15', N'Jim', 16, 16)
    ,   (N'2023-03-15', N'Steve', 5, 12)
) t (Date,Name,Actual,Target)

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = (   
    SELECT  '
    ,   SUM(case when name = ' + QUOTENAME(Name, '''') + ' then Actual END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Name + '_Actual') + N'
    ,   SUM(case when name = ' + QUOTENAME(Name, '''') + ' then Target END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Name + '_Targer')
    FROM    #yt
    GROUP BY Name
    ORDER BY Name
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 

SET @query = '
    SELECT  Date' + @cols + '
    FROM    #yt
    GROUP BY Date
            '
EXEC(@query);
```

This way, you have much more flexibility in handling both column names and values. The SUM(CASE WHEN ...) is the conditional aggregation part that fetches the needed values and places them in correct columns.

Comment: If I have a table called NamesTable and it has a column Names with all the people that work and I want to create the cols variable from there how would I do it? I know I can select all the names and format it into columns, but how do you select them all and add the _Target and _Actual?

Comment: Don't you already do that in your example? Or what's the difference?

Comment: Currently I have multiple tables that are linked and I'm grabbing data and creating CTEs and the CTE I end up with is the first table I showed in my question. Then I create the cols variable getting all the names from my NamesTable and then pivot the CTE on that. I didn't want to include all that in the question and make it too complicated. The CTEs don't cooperate well when I'm trying to grab the cols variable from them so I grab it from the NamesTable instead. If I want to grab the cols variable from NamesTable and create two columns per name with _Target and _Actual, how could I do that?

Comment: If you're currently creating a variable by doing something like: `SELECT @col = ... FROM TableX` what's stopping you from changing that to: `select @col = ... FROM NamesTable`. You can still get the actual data from your CTE later. This question makes me think that perhaps you need to first understand what this above code does, so you're not just copypasting stuff randomly

Comment: Please attach the whole code and what's the issue you're having, or i can delete this answer if it doesn't work

Comment: That did what I was asking for, sorry I was misunderstanding it and confusing myself with the way I was trying to ask the question. Thank you so much for your help!